# Why is there no mainstream JavaScript professional certification?

Tags: javascript

I am searching for online/real life (this one is sort of complicated because of my location: Bulgaria) courses and **certification** for JavaScript (of course if it includes `HTM`L and `css` is great as well). I stress more on the certification, since I am working with this technologies for the last two and a half years, and I am pretty confident of my skills, but of course there is always something new to learn.

Do you know a specific set of certifications that are popular and widely accepted?

I have taken the Microsoft 70-480 exam with basically no problem, but all of the paths that Microsoft have in there certification program are too much Microsoft oriented. I am searching for something more generic.

Comment: I don't think a Javascript certification will provide you any value, at least in the USA, from what I've seen. If you want to prove to an employer that you know Javascript, you'd be better off writing an open source project that Javascript based and showing it to them.

And I believe that websites like Behance allow you to take online tests to prove that you know Javascript or any other language, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: It has nothing to do about certification. It's more about your knowledge of how programming works and how the system works. Once you start learning a couple programming languages, they all pretty much are similar and/or use the same kind of logic. If you really are worried about **certification** the best certification is working on personal projects in javascript to show what you can do. I'd recommend working on some kind of node project that shows your proficiency.

Comment: Show your code, not some paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that any companies of relevance pay any attention to 'certifications.' You just can't tell if someone is a good programer that way. It's much more complex.

Problem solving and aptitude for learning are what the employers want.

This industry changes so fast, that if you know JavaScript, great - but do you know how to build a REST API? - Do you have node experience? Have you used React - or Ember - or Angular? - Have you build data visualisations? Do you understand the other front-end tech so that you build with the other team-members in mind? Are you seasoned enough that you know how to choose tools with wisdom - or do you jump on every new thing... Can you see how much work something will be from a distance? Can you budget time?

There are things like Tree house that will give you a nifty little badge for completing their courses - but that doesn't really mean anything without real-world experience.

I recommend reading a few books, like Douglas Crockford's JavaScript the Good Parts, and then the 'You don't know JS' series from Kyle Simpson - because they have a slightly different take on how to think about JavaScript, then just say - "I read those books, and I understood them, - here are a few projects I made on github to show you how I approach puzzles."

Comment: Echoing this notion, certification isn't usually really worth much in the front-end realm, the state of the art changes constantly so a year-old cert might mean nothing tomorrow.